# simplified print method from Word in VirtualBox in Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, microsoft-word, printing

The following method can print a document in Word (Office 2003) in Windows 8.1 in VirtualBox 4.3.6 in Ubuntu 12.04 with a HP DeskJet 2060 K110.

1. In Word click File, click Print, click OK, wait a while.
2. Click Start, right-click the UserName, select "Sign Out".
3. Click the Windows power button icon, click the off button, click restart, and wait about a minute until the busy indictor freezes.
4. Click the exit button provided by VirtualBox in the form of an Ubuntu window containing the guest, select "Power Off Windows", click OK.
5. In VitualBox, if necessary select Windows as the guest, click "Start"
6. Click the Windows 8.1 power symbol, click the password text box, type the password.

A simplified method is sought.

Edit: The printer is local and VirtualBox's passthrough capability appears enabled in the Devices menu, USB sub-menu.

Edit: I deleted the driver and re-installed it and printed a test page.  To print a test page I click "print test page" and then proceed with step 2, listed above.

Answer (score 0):

How are you connected to your LAN? If you choose the method *Bridge*, under Network-> Adapter 1 -> Attached to -> Bridge, and insert, in the Name box, the name of the adapter which your ubuntu host is currently using, then you will get an IP address from your router, as if your VM were a true pc connected to the LAN. At this point, you can install the network printer in your Windows VM, and print just like you would do it if you were on a hardware pc.

If the printer is not a network printer, then you have two solutions:

1) if it is a USB printer, just install the extension pack, and you can grab hold of it, and release it, as you see fit.

2) otherwise, you can share from your host using cups/samba, and when you scan for printers from within windows, it will apeear to you since it has been shared.

Comment: It's not a networked printer.  It is local and passed through VirtualBox.

Comment: @broyian read the new part of my post.

Comment: I think Windows is accessing the printer so the extension pack is probably already installed.  By "extension pack", I think you mean "Guest Additions" and mine is the latest, 4.3.6.

Comment: @broiyan Good, But then, from within Windows, you can print a test page. Does this work?

Comment: Yes, I can print a test page.